# LinkedList<T> with multiple Previous and Next

Tags: c#, .net, collections, linked-list

Does .NET provide linked collection class with multiple **Previous** and **Next**? I can spend some time to write my own class, but if .NET has ready-to-use solution, I'll prefer that.

The situation: I'm modeling some system of connected components, where any unit can be connected to any number of another units. This is not list and even not tree, this is a web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you need to build a graph.
Here is an article in MSDN about how to build graphs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379574(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: This is more a comment.